# Remove string based on start and end pattern and remove newline in the process

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a file that contains output of some commands - unfortunately some of them are mangled by console error:

```
path="/a/b/c" fxid="05200f4d" size="12550144" nrep="2" checksumtype="adler" checksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000"
nrep="01" fsid="132" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/data/00019507/3dcd7e00" size="4574568" statsize="45745error: unable to retrieve file meta data from cluster.local:1095 [ status=down ]
nrep="00" fsid="37" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/data/000021ca/0527e888" size="12550144" statsize="12550144" checksum="bb2a2ea700000000000000000000000000000000" diskchecksum="bb2a2ea700000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="nerror: unable to retrieve file meta data from cluster.local:1095 [ status=(null) ]
one"
path="/a/b/b98d6d3a-5c77-4223-9601-9294c73e00f9.bin" fxid="05200f4d" size="12550144" nrep="2" checksumtype="adler" checksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000"
nrep="01" fsid="36" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/data/00002196/05200f4d" size="12550144" statsize="12550144" checksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000" diskchecksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="nonerror: unable to retrieve file meta data from cluster.local:1095 [ status=(down) ]
e"
path="/a/b/c/.mb6589013703229118680.txt" fxid="0524071a" size="0" nrep="2" checksumtype="adler" checksum="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000"
nrep="00" fsid="196" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/dataerror: unable to retrieve file meta data from cluster.local:1095 [ status=(null) ]
/000021b0/0524071a" size="0" statsize="0" checksum="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000" diskchecksum="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="none"
```

Basically I'd like the string that starts with `error: unable` and ending with `]` character to be removed completely so instead of :

```
diskchecksum="bb2a2ea700000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="nerror: unable to retrieve file meta data from cluster.local:1095 [ status=(null) ]
one"
```

I will have:

```
diskchecksum="bb2a2ea700000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="none"
```

I have tried the following :

```
sed -e 's/error:.*]$//g'
```

However that gives me:

```
diskchecksum="bb2a2ea700000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="n
one"
```

How do I get it to remove the newline as well when its removing the bad string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu sed` you can do this:

```sh
sed '/error: unable.*/ {s///;N;s/\n//;}' file
```

Or using `awk`:

```sh
awk 'sub(/error: unable.*/, "") {s = $0; getline; print s $0}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` using awk's RS as null here. Written and tested in GNU `awk` here.

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/error: unable[^]]+]\n*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using global substitution to substitute `error: unable` till `]` till newlines(0 or more occurrences) with NULL and perform printing then.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/nerror:/{s/\(error_label=\)"nerror: unable[^]]*]/\1"none"/g;n;d}' input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for `-E` (to enable EREs) and `-z` (to read the whole file at once and so allow us to match newlines in the regexp):

```
$ sed -Ez 's/error: unable[^]]+](\r?\n)?//g' file
path="/a/b/c" fxid="05200f4d" size="12550144" nrep="2" checksumtype="adler" checksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000"
nrep="01" fsid="132" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/data/00019507/3dcd7e00" size="4574568" statsize="45745nrep="00" fsid="37" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/data/000021ca/0527e888" size="12550144" statsize="12550144" checksum="bb2a2ea700000000000000000000000000000000" diskchecksum="bb2a2ea700000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="none"
path="/a/b/b98d6d3a-5c77-4223-9601-9294c73e00f9.bin" fxid="05200f4d" size="12550144" nrep="2" checksumtype="adler" checksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000"
nrep="01" fsid="36" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/data/00002196/05200f4d" size="12550144" statsize="12550144" checksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000" diskchecksum="045a6aa400000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="none"
path="/a/b/c/.mb6589013703229118680.txt" fxid="0524071a" size="0" nrep="2" checksumtype="adler" checksum="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000"
nrep="00" fsid="196" host="cluster.local:1095" fstpath="/data/000021b0/0524071a" size="0" statsize="0" checksum="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000" diskchecksum="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" error_label="none"
```

The above accommodates you having newlines at the end of the text you want to match whether they're just `\n`s or `\r\n`s.